# Display Checkbox field from MySQL in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-activity, android-tablelayout

I have a MySQL database that has some yes/no fields that are set up as TINYINT(1) in mysql. I'm displaying information from that table into a table layout on android. How do I get those fields to show as a checkbox in android since the values in those fields are 0 for no and anything except 0 for yes? Or is there a better way of doing this by changing the field type in mysql?

Here is my MainActivity.java in case you would like to see it. It currently is only displaying 3 text fields from the table.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 String data = "";
 TableLayout tl;
 TableRow tr;
 TextView label;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

    final GetDataFromDB getdb = new GetDataFromDB();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
            System.out.println(data);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<Users> users = parseJSON(data);
                    addData(users);
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}

public ArrayList<Users> parseJSON(String result) {
    ArrayList<Users> Suppliers = new ArrayList<Users>();
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Users user = new Users();
     //       user.setId(json_data.getInt("id"));
            user.setDelivery_date(json_data.getString("Delivery_Date"));
            user.setOrder(json_data.getString("Order"));
            user.setHauler(json_data.getString("Haulers_HaulerID"));
            Suppliers.add(user);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return Suppliers;
}

void addHeader(){
    /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
    tr = new TableRow(this);

    /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
    label = new TextView(this);
    label.setText("Delivery Date");
    label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    label.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
    //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.addView(label,params);
    tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    TextView supplier = new TextView(this);
    supplier.setText("Order");
    supplier.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    supplier.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    supplier.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
    //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.addView(supplier,params);
    tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

    TextView hauler = new TextView(this);
    hauler.setText("Hauler");
    hauler.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    hauler.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    hauler.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
    //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.addView(hauler,params);
    tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

    // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
public void addData(ArrayList<Users> users) {

    addHeader();

    for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

        Users p = (Users) i.next();

        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText(p.getDelivery_date());
      //  label.setId(p.getId());
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView supplier = new TextView(this);
        supplier.setText(p.getOrder());
        supplier.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        supplier.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        supplier.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(supplier,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView hauler = new TextView(this);
        hauler.setText(p.getHauler());
        hauler.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        hauler.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        hauler.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(hauler,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Users` data object, so I think you should have a boolean property in the Users object, convert the JSON integer to boolean on parse, and use the boolean to set the checkbox:

```
class Users {

    .
    .
    .
    private boolean mFlag;

    public boolean isFlag() {
        return mFlag;
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        mFlag = flag;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

parse:

```
 user.setFlag(json_data.getInt("Flag") != 0);
```

display:

```
CheckBox cbFlag = new CheckBox(activity);

cbFlag.setChecked(user.isFlag());
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thank you. Is there a way to lock the checkboxes from being edited on this screen. My next tasks are to add activities to add and edit this table but this screen is just to display information. My concern is someone could check checkbox "Order Placed: yes/no" and think it would update to the table then someone else sees it hasn't been placed and orders another load.

Comment: cbFlag.setClickable(false);